# Logic in for loop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, for-loop

I am having some problem when trying to perform some calculation inside a for loop using JavaScript:

```
for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    var attributes;
    if (latlng !== 'Null') {
        attributes = results[j].feature.attributes;
    }                               
    var totalYC = parseInt(attributes["AGE_0_2"] + attributes["AGE_3_4"] + attributes["AGE_5_6"]);      
    var r = {
        pa: attributes["Planning Area Name"],
        sitearea: parseFloat(attributes["SHAPE_Area"] * 0.0001),
        total_pop: parseInt(attributes["TOTAL_POPULATION"]),
        scpr: parseInt(attributes["TOTAL_SCPR"]),
        yc: parseInt(totalYC),
        age_0_2: parseInt(attributes["AGE_0_2"]),
        age_3_4: parseInt(attributes["AGE_3_4"]),
        age_5_6: parseInt(attributes["AGE_5_6"]),        
    };

    r_array.push(r);
}
```

I want my totalYC to sum up for the total of `attributes["AGE_0_2"] + attributes["AGE_3_4"] + attributes["AGE_5_6"]` just for once only. Let's say `attributes["AGE_0_2"]` is 1, `attributes["AGE_3_4"]` is 2 and `attributes["AGE_5_6"]` is 3. The totalYC should be 6 but not looping thru the entire for loop and keep on plusing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each time through the loop uses a different attributes array (taken from results[j] for different values of j each time). Each pass should create a different 'r' value that gets pushed, each having `yc` as the total of those values for that particular pass.  What are you seeing that's wrong?

Comment: But the value I am having is way too big. The problem comes from the for loop because it keeps on adding each time

Comment: ehm, could you add a plunker?

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would keep increasing the value of 'attributes' and thus totalYC. Can you parseInt() each value individually and see if it makes any difference?

    parseInt(attributes["AGE_0_2"]) + parseInt(attributes["AGE_3_4"]) + parseInt(attributes["AGE_5_6"]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the items individually before adding them together.

Using your example of

- attributes["AGE_0_2"] is 1
- attributes["AGE_3_4"] is 2
- attributes["AGE_5_6"] is 3

your code

```
var totalYC = parseInt(attributes["AGE_0_2"] + attributes["AGE_3_4"] + attributes["AGE_5_6"]);
```

is probably returning `123`

If you change to

```
var totalYC = parseInt(attributes["AGE_0_2"]) + parseInt(attributes["AGE_3_4"]) + parseInt(attributes["AGE_5_6"]);
```

you should now get `6`

**EDIT**

Because JavaScript doesn't have typed variables it assumes that you are appending strings together.

So when you type `attributes["AGE_0_2"] + attributes["AGE_3_4"] + attributes["AGE_5_6"]` it is like you are saying `"1" + "2" + "3"`. JavaScript will try to append these values together which returns `"123"`.

Using the `ParseInt` method tells JavaScript to try and parse these variables as numbers first. JavaScript is smart enough to know that the `+` operator is therefore a math operator and not an append.